# 2$\pi$-peridodic and continuous function with non summable Fourier coeffficients

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Can someone tell me an example of 2$\pi$-periodic and continuous function, f,  with Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(n)\;\forall{n\in{\mathbb{Z}}}$ such that $\sum|\hat{f}(n)|>\infty$?

Thanks.

Comment: try some continuous function that approximates the sign function in $[-\pi,\pi]$. My idea comes from the fact that the Fourier coefficients of the periodic extension of the sign function in $[-\pi,\pi]$ are $1/n$ for odd $n$ (an zero for even $n$)

Comment: You may also need to prevent your function from being differentiable in order to force the coefficients to be large.

Comment: I have tried a Weirstrass type function: $f(t)=\sum\frac{1}{n!}cos((n!)^2t)$. But it doesn't work no?

Comment: Would $\sin(\csc x)\sin x$ work with the value zero at multiples of $\pi$ work?  The function is continuous but nondifferentiable at these multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: I'm quite sure there is no function whose Fourier coefficients sum to a value strictly greater than infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Convergence of Fourier Series is a delicate business but everything is known. The theorem you are looking for is the following:

> (Du Bois-Reymond 1873) There is a continuous function $f: [-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\limsup_{N} \sum_{|n| \le N} \widehat{f}(n) \rightarrow \infty$.

A standard proof of this result can be found all over the internet but I think the most elementary construction is given [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuous-function-with-divergent-fourier-series/).

Just as a reference, if you know that your function is in $C^1$ then the Fourier series converges uniformly. Furthermore, if you know that your function is in $L^p$ for $p > 1$ then your Fourier series converges pointwise for everything in your compact interval except possibly on a set of measure $0$. This is the celebrated [Carleson-Hunt Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem).